# Mozilla firefox, как решить проблему в manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, расширения

При добавлении временного расширения в mozilla firefox проблему:
`Extension is invalid. Reading manifest: Property "description" is unsupported in Manifest Version 1.`

Сам manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Запускаем снежинки на любом сайте",
  "description": "Проект журнала Код",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 1,

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: А почему вы используете Manifest Version 1, а не 2?

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Но теперь он не видит popup.html. Создавал расширение по https://thecode.media/extention/

Comment: В вашей ссылке manifest_version указан вообще 3

Comment: Соглашусь, но с 3 версией он выдаёт мне `Unsupported manifest version: 3`

Comment: Потому что Firefox ещё не реализовал версию 3, да. Или переходите на Chrome, или найдите какой-нибудь другой урок для манифеста версии 2. Для разных манифестов расширения пишутся по-разному, нельзя просто так взять и поменять циферку от балды

Comment: Ясно, благодарствую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ спрятан в тексте ошибки: "Property "description" is unsupported in Manifest Version 1". Думаю, @andreymal прав. Нужно версию поправить

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Но теперь он не видит popup.html. Создавал расширение по https://thecode.media/extention/

Comment: В приведенной вами странице есть пример в котором версия 3 указана:

```
{
  «name»: «Запускаем снежинки на любом сайте»,
  «description»: «Проект журнала Код»,
  «version»: «1.0»,
  «manifest_version»: 3
}
```